# Empty Kibana Screen, Kibana not showing Data

Tags: interface, elasticsearch, localhost, kibana

Getting empty/blank screen (except for a few buttons on the top toolbar) in kibana.

I have elasticsearch 3.3.2 running on my localhost. I downloaded kibana-3.1.2. I unzipped the file and copied the contents of the extracted directory into my webserver. I copied then into "C:\inetpub\wwwroot". The config.js file is unmodified, because I am running on localhost and this will work for now.
The kibana folder now shows up in ISS under default Web site.

![enter image description here][1]

When I have an instance of elasticsearch running (verified by entering `http://localhost:9200` in web browser)

I enter `"http://localhost/kibana-3.1.2/"` into my web browser (I have tried this in chrome and firefox).
This automatically redirects me to `"http://localhost/kibana-3.1.2/#/dashboard/file/default.json"` and shows the template of the kibana page but I can't do anything in it, and it doesn't have a "getting started guide" like the instillation instructions said there would be.

![enter image description here][2]

I don't know what I have missed or what I did wrong.

Comment: kibana by default points to port 5601. I believe you are missing that.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I have the same issue with kibana 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the Kibana javascript is unable to load default.json from IIS. You need to add a MIME Type mapping for the .json extension. Map it to application/json.

If you still get an empty dashboard, change the application pool used by the site to "No Managed Code" and "Classic" and recycle the application pool.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the 
elasticsearch: "http://localhost:9200"
in kibana.yml?
Otherwise it might be the nginx configuration (that was the case for me).
BTW, an easy way to check is to download the Kibana 4 Beta which doesn't run on port 80 and doesn't require nginx (or other)...

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Kibana 3 with tomcat server.. copy kibana folder into tomcat server,webapps folder... and run with the link "localhost:8080/kibana-3.1.2"  (8080 ----> Give as per your tomcat port).

Now your kibana will start.